# BasichttpBinding vs WSHttpBinding of WCF

Tags: wcf

I want to update client data with server data and vice-versa. Currently i am using BasicHttpBinding which is faster than wsHttpBinding.
My requirnment is to achive:

- Fast data communication
- Secure communication

Two binding is suitable in this scenario BasicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding.
So which Binding should i use ? and What is the difference between BasicHttp and wsHttp binding ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need security, use `wsHttpBinding`. It implements all the various security features, like message or transport security, client credentials provided as Windows credentials, username/password, or certificate. It supports reliable messaging and a lot more - a whole slew of the WS* standards.

`BasicHttpBinding` is just that - very very basic. It's more or less ASMX web services - pretty much no settings, no security (other than being routed over HTTPS).

If you need fast, use `netTcpBinding` - but that doesn't work well over internet connections. If that doesn't work, use `basicHttpBinding` - it's faster, leaner, less overhead than `wsHttpBinding`.

So you're back to the classic trade-off: you can have fast or secure - pick one. There's no "magic" way of having both at the same time - security does add overhead and thus slows things down. What is more important to you: secure communications, or fast communications??

Comment: security is more important for me. can we implement ssl with basicHttpBinding or only wsHttpbinding is campatible with security thing. If we can use ssl with basicHttpBinding then what will be significant performance difference in basicHttp and wsHttp Bindings.

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan: Probably very late, but for anyone else reading this: Yes, it is possible - Just use Security Mode: `Message`. Message Security provides end-to-end transport-independent security.

Comment: @DerekW, Thank you. Is there any article or example for it? So I can read further and understand more

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan: Here's an overview of Message Security: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137(v=vs.110).aspx and here's an example where HTTPS is not needed (you will need an X.509 certificate on the server as it provides encryption): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DerekW, Thanks a ton. I will go through those links

Answer (score 6):

wsHTttpBinding implemenets the WS-Security standard for web services communication, however, I believe HTTPS will provide you with sufficient security if you use basicHttpBinding.

You should also keep in mind that wsHttpBinding restricts your interoperability, as wsHttpBinding is only compatible with clients that support WS-* (SOAP 1.2).

In my opinion, I would stick with basicHttpBinding unless there are specific WS-* standard features that you need.  In terms of WS-Security, the features it comes with is things like message level encryption (beyond the transport level encryption that HTTPS provides).  To me, transport encryption ensures your message is encrypted when transmitted over the wire, the only benefit of having message level encryption is not wanting the overhead of using transport level security, but just wanting lighter weight encryption in specific areas of the message.

Here's a list of WS specifications from wikipedia for your information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_service_specifications

Comment: Transport security can be beneficial when the communication is not known to be over a point-to-point, secured channel. When a client issues messages to a service and message is routed through intermediaries, transport security cannot always be guaranteed, and message-level security becomes a useful option.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we recommend a fast secure transport like SSL for security. This is because any kind of message level security is CPU intensive in encryption/signing.

SO you can just use basic http binding with transport security for most scenarios without too much of trade off in perf.

If you aren't using any of the richer WS* protocols or sessions etc then you can stick with basic http binding.